# Laravel 5.5 LaravelCollective Form in Blade - calls Validator before Controller@store

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

Validator for UNIQUE generates SQL from DatabasePresenceVerifier for the form request which has required|unique validation rules. Removing unique the validator works fine for the other rules.
Validator for UNIQUE uses the default SQL connection instead of the connection currently set in the Model of the field being validated.

I have code in the Controller Store method to change the connection before the Validator is called, but the Controller Store method is not being called when form is submitted. All the documentation about custom validator says the Store method is where it goes.
Validator is called by Blade before the Model Controller Store method has been called. It uses the default SQL connection and can't find the database where the attribute needs to be validated.

Any idea where or how the Blade form is calling the Validator so I can add my custom code to set the SQL connection?
Alternatively, can I turn off the Blade validation and let my Store method call the validator as documented?

Comment: You can add the connection to the validation rule like this ['unique:connection.table,column'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: That works, thank you so much. It also fixed the syntax with the query string in my other question, very unexpected.